# software R: Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, statistics, geostatistics

I have three parameters with 899 points each, but one of them shows this message when I try to apply any command.

Even the simplest command appears like this, for example:

```
>basicStats(Values$Values.of.Th)
Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The three parameters are similar, I can't understand why it works for the others and not for him.
I started studying R recently, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you _sure_ it is a numeric variable? Perhaps it is a character vector or factor variable that looks like a numeric variable. What is `class(Values$Values.of.Th)`?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.